# Sublime documentation, example not working, one python error then another

Tags: python, sublimetext2

Looking at documentation for sublime plugin examples (something I googled) I got .  [a link from the sublime site](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-examples)

First I was getting the no module error "ImportError: No module named sublimeplugin" with lines  `import sublime, sublimeplugin` and `class Rot13Command(sublimeplugin.TextCommand):` 
Though running `view.run_command('rot13')` still worked despite the error (or did earlier anyway though doesn't now).

Then I added an _ because I read on their forum (which is not particularly active), that it should have an underscore now [link](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&p=54408).

Then, that got rid of the "no module..." error

but when I enter this command in the console- `view.run_command('rot13')`
I get this error `"TypeError: run() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)"`

Below is my code just taken from that link but adding an underscore, how can I fix that error?

```
http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-examples
CODE: SELECT ALL
import sublime, sublime_plugin  

class Rot13Command(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):  
    def run(self, view, args):  
        for region in view.sel():  
            if not region.empty():  
                # Get the selected text  
                s = view.substr(region)  
                # Transform it via rot13  
                s = s.encode('rot13')  
                # Replace the selection with transformed text  
                view.replace(region, s)
```

Comment: also perhaps a bug with sublime, sometimes working code didn't run, one time that happened I tried  changing the name of the class like from RotaCommand to Rota5Command then it ran and I changed it back to RotaCommand. dunno what that was about. not 100% sure that happened but that seemed to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation appears to conform to the original [Sublime Text API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api-reference), and not the [Sublime Text 2 API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html).
Printing the arguments that are given to `run`, it is apparent that neither `view` nor `args` are passed. Instead, it recieves a lone `Edit` object.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class RotCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            print type(arg)

#later, in the console:
>>> view.run_command('rot')
<class 'sublime.Edit'>
```

Luckily, you can still access the `view` object. It's a member of `self`. While you're making changes, add the `edit` parameter to `view.replace`.

```
class RotCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        for region in self.view.sel():
            if not region.empty():
                # Get the selected text
                s = self.view.substr(region)
                # Transform it via rot13
                s = s.encode('rot13')
                # Replace the selection with transformed text
                self.view.replace(edit, region, s)
```

Running `view.run_command('rot')` now translates the text you have selected. `hello I am some sample text` becomes `uryyb V nz fbzr fnzcyr grkg`.

Comment: also well spotted re on the bottom of this page http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/   it says "How to Create a Sublime Text 2 Plugin"  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone viewing this in 2019:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import codecs

class Rot13Command(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  """docstring for Rot13Command"""
  def run(self, edit):
    for region in self.view.sel():
      if not region.empty():
        # Get the selected text
        s = self.view.substr(region)
        # Transform it via rot13
        s = codecs.encode(s, "rot-13")
        # Replace the selection with transformed text
        self.view.replace(edit, region, s)
```

Comment: is that still ST2?

Comment: 3.1.1.  Latest version.